# How can I print list of items from multiple lines into a single line in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert items list from multiple lines to a single line string and vice-versa. I am  able to convert items from a single line string to multiple line vertical item list with following code:

```
Items = ["Apple","Ball","Cat"]
A = ("\n".join(Items))
print (A)
```

Which prints item list as follows:

```
Apple  
Ball  
Cat
```

**I am all set with above code**
**My Question is regarding second code (which I can't figure out) down below:**

However, I am unable to convert vertical list from multiple lines to a single line string.

I have following items in multiple lines;

```
 Apple  
 Ball  
 Cat
```

and I want to print them in a single line as:

```
 Apple Ball Cat
```

I appreciate any kind of advice.

Comment: Experiment with `str.split` a little, especially `str.split('\n')`

Comment: Use `' '.join` instead of `\n`

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Are you using the words "string" and "list" interchangeably or is that just my imagination? Anyway, if I understand correctly, I think `' '.join(Items)` solves your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Replace your code with this:

```
A = (" ".join(Items))
```

Comment: @Simon Thank you for responding, probably I didn't frame my question correctly. I am all set with first part, **my question was second part;** how to convert convert vertical list from multiple lines to a single line string.

Comment: @dumb_guy I think you have commented to the wrong person.  I just edited the post

Comment: @Simon My bad... Thanks, that was meant to be  Alberto , However, I can use your advice as well.

Comment: @dumb_guy I think you find that sorts your problem.  I arranges it all on the same line, unless I misread your question.  This works for me.

Comment: @dumb_guy At the end of your code add: print(A.replace('\n',' '))

Comment: @Alberto thank you very much, that worked out fine except one extra white space at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You are joining the items with a new line character `'\n'`. Try joining them with just a space `' '`.

So instead of

```
Items = ["Apple","Ball","Cat"]
A = ("\n".join(Items))
print (A)
```

You do

```
Items = ["Apple","Ball","Cat"]
A = (" ".join(Items))
print (A)
```

Answer (score 0):

No `join()` required

```
things = ["Apple","Ball","Cat"]
s1 = ''

for item in things:
    s1 += item + ' '

print(s1.rstrip())

# output
''' Apple Ball Cat '''
```

Answer (score 0):

print(A,end="") replace the last line with this

Answer (score -1):

skills = ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript", "PHP", "Python"]
while skills:print("\n".join(skills)); break

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).